# is password sent encrypted for authentication?

Tags: postgresql

Below is my pg_hba.conf entry.

```
host     dbname         username    0.0.0.0/0   radius radiusserver=xyz radiussecret=xyz
```

My understanding here is that when client is trying to establish connection to postgres, the password is sent to postgres which in turns passes it to radius to perform authentication. Once okayed from Radius, the connection will be established. Please correct me if this is not right.

1. Now when the password is sent to db, will it be unencrypted? I think so.
2. When password is sent to Radius, is it encrypted?
3. If I covert host entry to hostssl, then when the client sends the password it would be encrypted correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the password is plain text to the PostgreSQL server, provided the connection itself is unencrypted.
2. Yes, apparently it is encrypted/hashed between the PostgreSQL server and the radius server, but apparently just with a md5 hash, so not the greatest.  There might be additional ways to protect it, but I think that would be a radius question, not a postgresql question.
3. Yes, ssl will protect it between the client and PostgreSQL, but using hostssl in pg_hba is the wrong way to do it if you are worried about sending the plain-text password to a compromised server.  The person who compromised the server will just change "hostssl" back to "host", if they are any good.  Instead, you want to enforce this on the client end, with `PGSSLMODE=verify-full` or the equivalent. (Actually they don't need to turn ssl off, as it will be encrypted **for them** to decrypt anyway)